# What is the general definition of signal acceptance?

Tags: particle-physics, experimental-physics, standard-model, simulations

Suppose I have a beyond Standard Model theory and want to test it. I want to test if some experiments, say conduced in LHC, show signals of the theory.

In this case, what is "signal acceptance"?

Answer (score 4):

Acceptance is some measure of the fraction of events or the spacial or momentum distributions of events that will be registered in the detector. The exact meaning varies from experiment to experiment and sometimes from analysis to analysis within a single experimental data set.

Understanding the acceptance of a experiment for a particular signal can be a very big job and often requires a quality Monte Carlo as it is not amenable to analytic computation.

Comment: If I set a threshold, say 50 GeV, that is, only particles with at least 50 GeV energy will be registered by the detector, then I think this will contribute to acceptance. In order to calculate the acceptance, I need to know the distribution of particle as a function of its energy. Then the acceptance will be the percentage of the area above 50 GeV and under the curve of distribution (theoretically). Is this correct?

Comment: Some people lump selection into acceptance, some do not. The important thing is to make clear what each of the several multiplicative factors that go into your rate computation mean. Personally I think of them as separate: acceptance rules what potential events generate a signal in the detector and selection is a separate step in which you decide what signals to consider.