# What is the difference between selection efficiency and acceptance in high energy physics?

Tags: particle-physics, terminology, data-analysis

Often in papers the product of these two quantities is mentioned, but I'm not sure what exactly they mean separately.

My guess would be that one of these is the fraction of the events that you are interested in that pass the trigger system, and the other is the fraction passing your cuts in the analysis.

Comment: miha priimek: "_My guess would be that one of these_" -- acceptance -- "_is the fraction of the events that you are interested in that pass the trigger system, and the other is the fraction passing your cuts in the analysis._" -- That's my (somewhat educated) rough guess, too. A little more detailed, there might be events for which data readout was triggered but for which nevertheless some specific information was not available on which otherwise a selection cut would've been applied. Also, "_selection efficieny_" may refer to background reduction, or maximizing S^2 / (S + B), etc.

Comment: "Acceptance" tends to be the fraction of signal events visible to your detector due to its geometry (particularly important in LHCb, for example). Selection efficiency is the fraction of signal events that pass your selection cuts. Trigger and reconstruction efficiency are sometimes factored out of the latter.

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/150156/what-is-the-general-definition-of-signal-acceptance